# Setting role based access control

Tags: users

Since we launched we have added many new job roles and wish to set all new wiki pages so everyone can access. At present we are having to manually tick each role.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have too many roles to tick each role to set permissions you should probably rethink your roles. Why not just give editing permissions to authenticated user?

Comment: Another option would be too look into something like https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_permissions

Comment: take a look at https://drupal.org/project/permissions_api and https://drupal.org/project/permission_select

Answer (score 0):

Tick "Authenticated User" and the rest will automatically become ticked